# Low performance of react app after deployment

Tags: reactjs

I have worked on my react application and after deployment, there is very low performance of the app

Github repository link

https://github.com/Elue-dev/react-app/tree/main/react-site/react-site

Comment: Try Lighthouse/ Web.dev and check out what is causing your site to be slow.

Answer (score 1):

I cloned your repo inside codesandbox and found the problem.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-oskar-iiyvv

You are loading big images to the front end. Each of your images is more than 2mb in size.

First of all you should compress the images and ideally make really small
Then google the term `lazy-loading` and implement that in your application